# Python ConfigParser, Interpolation in the DEFAULT section, possible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I am using `SafeConfigParser`, my configuration file includes a `[DEFAULT]` section and I am using the below code to extract that part.

```
parser = SafeConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
parser.optionxform = str  # makes names case sensitive
defaultAttributesDic = parser.defaults()
```

However my `DEFAULT` section include **interpolated values** such as:

```
A= 10000
B= %(A)s
```

But the problem is that `defaults()` returns the actual raw values (not interpolated values).
Why is that? when can that be useful? I don't get the reason behind this decision?

I am using `parser.items(section)` to read other sections and that works fine. Values are returned interpolated. Should i skip `defaults` and use `items("DEFAULT")` instead? Please explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[defaults()](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.defaults) is a method inherited from [RawConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#rawconfigparser-objects) which **doesn't** support interpolation.

I think you should reserve the `[DEFAULT]` section for providing defaults for other sections instead of trying to *"abuse"* it as a *"normal"* section. The `[DEFAULT]` section has a special meaning and isn't even included in methods like `sections()` or `has_section()`.

If you need a *"default"* section just call it a name other than `DEFAULT`.